# Query after mutation is done with VueJS 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Im pretty new to vue and the whole topic but my goal is to run a myUser query after the jwt token is saved.

JWT saving is working but i have no clue how the proceed after the mutation is done.
Im thinking about a watch() on loggedIn ref but im not sure.
Tried several things, but no solution found and due the lack of information in the www im hoping for you help.

Here is my core logic

```
    <script>
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';
    import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
    import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue';
    import { useUserStore } from '../stores/user';
    import { myUser } from '@/apollo/queries';
    import { loginUser } from '@/apollo/mutations';
    
    export default {
       name: 'LoginForm',
    
       setup() {
          let username = ref('');
          let password = ref('');
          let loggedIn = ref(false);
    
          const error = computed(() => {
             return username.value === '' ? 'The username is required' : '';
          });
    
          const {
             mutate: loginUserMutation,
             onDone,
             onError,
          } = useMutation(loginUser);
    
          onDone((res) => {
             if (
                res?.data?.loginUser && res.data.loginUser.success
             ) {
                localStorage.setItem('access-token', res.data.loginUser.msg);
    
                useUserStore().$patch({
                   username: res.data.loginUser.msg,
                });
    
                loggedIn.value = true;

>>>>>>>>>>> Now with the JWT token, call myUser query <<<<<<<<<<
             }
          });
    
          const loginBtnClicked = () => {
             loginUserMutation({
                username: username.value,
                password: password.value,
                platform: 'PC',
             });
          };
    
          return {
             username,
             password,
             error,
             loginBtnClicked,
             loginUserMutation,
          };
       },
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about...

create function `const myUser() => { -> myuser query logic... }`

after `localStorage.setItem('access-token', res.data.loginUser.msg);`
you call `myUser` function

Comment: I added following function in my setup method: 

const myUserQuery = () => {
         const { result } = useQuery(myUser);

         watch(result, value => {
          console.log(value);
         })
      };

and calling in in my onDone method but im getting following error: 

`index.ts?5bff:59 Uncaught (in promise) ApolloError: Apollo client with id default not found. Use provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup.`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).